# Using Squeel or Meta_where with Sinatra

Tags: sinatra, squeel, meta-where

I am using the ActiveRecord stuff in Sinatra and I'm wondering if it will work with meta_where or (preferably) squeel?

I'm going to start trying but I was hoping perhaps someone could short circuit me.

Answer (score 2):

Bo,

You can use Squeel with ActiveRecord in any framework you like. It's not Rails-specific. :)